# Update format of more than one cell with updateCells API request

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to center align a range of cells, but only the first cell in the range is updated with the specified format.

Here is my code:

```
align = 'CENTER'
data={
      "requests": [
        {
          "updateCells": {
            "rows": [
              {
                "values": [
                  {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                      "horizontalAlignment": align,
                      "textFormat":  { 
                        "fontFamily": fontFamily,
                        "fontSize":  fontSize
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "range": {
              "sheetId": sheetId,
              "startRowIndex": startRowIndex,
              "endRowIndex": endRowIndex,
              "startColumnIndex": startColumnIndex,
              "endColumnIndex": endColumnIndex
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

If I log the values - i.e. `print (startRowIndex, endRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endColumnIndex)` - they are correct (e.g. `0 1 27 30`), yet only the first cell is updated to the format - not the whole range.

What's going on here? How can I apply the specified format to the whole range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to update "AB1:AD1" (`{startRowIndex: 0, endRowIndex: 1, startColumnIndex: 27, endColumnIndex: 30}`). If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified points :

- When 3 columns are updated, the values are also required to be updated. In your case, you want to update 3 columns. So it is required to create like `{values: [{userEnteredFormat: ###}, {userEnteredFormat: ###}, {userEnteredFormat: ###}]}`.

#### Modified request :

```
{
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "updateCells": 
      {
        "rows": 
        [
          {
            "values": 
            [
              {
                "userEnteredFormat": 
                {
                  "horizontalAlignment": align ,   #'CENTER','LEFT','RIGHT',
                  "textFormat": 
                  {
                    "fontFamily": fontFamily,
                    "fontSize": fontSize
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "userEnteredFormat": 
                {
                  "horizontalAlignment": align ,   #'CENTER','LEFT','RIGHT',
                  "textFormat": 
                  {
                    "fontFamily": fontFamily,
                    "fontSize": fontSize
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "userEnteredFormat": 
                {
                  "horizontalAlignment": align ,   #'CENTER','LEFT','RIGHT',
                  "textFormat": 
                  {
                    "fontFamily": fontFamily,
                    "fontSize": fontSize
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "range": 
        {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": startRowIndex,
          "endRowIndex": endRowIndex,
          "startColumnIndex": startColumnIndex,
          "endColumnIndex": endColumnIndex
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit :

When you want to reflect the format for a lot of cells, you can use `repeatCell`. The request body is as follows. In this sample, all cells in the range are modified .

#### Modified request :

```
{
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "repeatCell": 
      {
        "cell": 
        {
          "userEnteredFormat": 
          {
            "horizontalAlignment": align ,   #'CENTER','LEFT','RIGHT',
            "textFormat":
             {
               "fontFamily": fontFamily,
               "fontSize": fontSize
             }
          }
        },
        "range": 
        {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": startRowIndex,
          "endRowIndex": endRowIndex,
          "startColumnIndex": startColumnIndex,
          "endColumnIndex": endColumnIndex
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Reference :

- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

Comment: really? that can't be. what if I wanted to update 1000 cells at a time with the same format? I would have to put in 1000 of these values? that can't be. what's the point of the "range" then?

Comment: @jason I'm really sorry I couldn't notice that you want to use such situation. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Japanese people are so helpful and respectful... i remember landing in Tokyo and an officer inspecting my bags... he took everything out, but when he put everything back, he packed it even better than how i packed it. I was shocked, humbled and honored all at the same time.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. It worked. I'm not sure why anybody would ever want to use `updateCells` instead of `repeatCell` ... for single cell, I can just use `repeatCell` and use a range of `AB1:AB1`.

Comment: @jason I'm honored for it. I'm glad your issue was solved. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: @jason I think that when ``updateCells`` is used, the special cells can be modified using like ``[[format1, format2, format3],,,]``. On the other hand, ``repeatCell`` can be used for modifying a lot of cells by the same format. At first, I had thought that you wanted the former. I'm sorry.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. No need to apologize. I understand now.

Comment: @jason Thank you, too.