# How to request updateCells for multiple rows to have the same value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm using this request code to insert those checkboxes in a column, but I also need to have them all set to true by default. So far I've seen examples with multiple "values", one for every row, but I would like to know if there's a way to declare that only once and already set for all others in a range

```
var resource = {"requests": [
    {"repeatCell": {
      "cell": {"dataValidation": {"condition":{"type": "BOOLEAN"}}},
      "range": {"sheetId": sheetId, "startRowIndex": 1, "endRowIndex": 300, "startColumnIndex": 18},
      "fields": "dataValidation"
      }
    },
    {"updateCells": {
      "rows": {"values": {"userEnteredValue": {"boolValue": true}}},
      "range": {"sheetId": sheetId, "startRowIndex": 1, "endRowIndex": 300, "startColumnIndex": 18},
      "fields": "userEnteredValue"
      }
    }
  ]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
```

Comment: Why use both `repeatCell` and `updateCells`? Just use `repeatCell` with the target range and a single cell definition if they're all the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885223/9337071

Comment: I tried with only repeatCell and looks like my problem is with "fields", since I need to repeat both userEnteredValue and dataValidation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use both `repeatCell` and `updateCells` requests, a single `repeatCell` request can be used to alter both the "data validation" and the "user entered value" properties of the desired range. The key is that both the "fields" parameter, which indicates the properties to be modified, and the actual properties, must all be included (or intentionally omitted, for deletion).

All cells in the specified range (R2C19:R301C19, since "_____Index" means -> 0-base) will then be modified to use the specified properties as found in your request:

```
var resource = {"requests": [
  {"repeatCell": {
    "cell": {
      "dataValidation": {"condition":{"type": "BOOLEAN"}},
      "userEnteredValue": {"boolValue": true}
    },
    "range": {
      "sheetId": sheetId,
      "startRowIndex": 1,
      "endRowIndex": 300,
      "startColumnIndex": 18,
      "endColumnIndex": 19 // Specify the end to insert only one column of checkboxes
    },
    "fields": "dataValidation,userEnteredValue"
  }
}]};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
```

Note that if you omit the `endColumnIndex`, the [`GridRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#GridRange) is interpreted as unbounded:

> All indexes are zero-based. Indexes are half open, e.g the start index is inclusive and the end index is exclusive -- [`startIndex`, `endIndex`). Missing indexes indicate the range is unbounded on that side.

References:

- [Valid `batchUpdate` requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request)
- [`repeatCell` request structure](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)
- [`CellData` resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData)
- [The `"fields"` parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial-response)
- [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885054/update-format-of-more-than-one-cell-with-updatecells-api-request/50885223#50885223)

Comment: Thanks, I had been tried with repeatCells only and my problem is that I was setting "fields": {"dataValidation", "userEnteredValue"} instead of having both inside the same string. 

Again, ty a lot

Comment: No worries. Google has a fair number of things related to their APIs that take an `Array` of `String`s. Whenever you see `fields` in their APIs though, it's a single csv string with some related specifications.

Comment: @DanielSouza I've added a few more links, including one about the general format / syntax allowed for the "fields" parameter.

Comment: thank you again, I'm already reading, it will be much helpful for sure